# Google Analytics Goal Regex URL

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I'm kind of new to regular expressions and can't figure out what the regular expression for this Google Analytics Goal URL should be.

The URL

```
examplesite.com/order/898/card
```

Should be considered the same as

```
examplesite.com/order/card
```

But not the same as

```
examplesite.com/order/898/delivery
```

So basically I want the regular expression for the URL

```
examplesite.com/order/*card
```

and

```
examplesite.com/order/*delivery
```

Etc.

I've Googled for something like this, but regular expressions for me are still al little to difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
examplesite.com/order/(\d+/)?card
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]